# HackerRank:- Day 4: Class vs. Instance, some weird error for some reason

Tags: c++, c++14

Getting error for this test :- https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-class-vs-instance/problem?h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen
One test case is failing for some reason, when I ran it in my IDE, it gave same output as expected, help me find out what I missed, I am very beginner level coder, moving from Civil Engg background so I am sorry if mistake is really silly. My code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Person{
    public:
        int age;
        Person(int initialAge);
        void amIOld();
        void yearPasses();
    };

    Person::Person(int initialAge){
        if (initialAge < 0){
            this->age=0;
            cout << "Age is not valid, setting age to 0.";
        }
        else {
            this->age = initialAge;
        }

    }

    void Person::amIOld(){
        if(age < 13){
            cout << "\nYou are young.";
        }
        else if (age >= 13 && age < 18) {
            cout << "\nYou are a teenager.";
        }
        else {
            cout << "\nYou are old.";
        }
    }

    void Person::yearPasses(){
        age++;
    }

int main(){
    int t;
    int age;
    cin >> t;
    for(int i=0; i < t; i++) {
        cin >> age;
        Person p(age);
        p.amIOld();
        for(int j=0; j < 3; j++) {
            p.yearPasses(); 
        }
        p.amIOld();

        cout << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: BTW, you can save yourself some typing by not doing `this->`.  Access the variable directly: e.g. `age = initialAge;`  The constructor doesn't require the `this->` notation and you don't use the notation in other methods.

Comment: Maybe it is your newline handling. In the ctor when age is less than 0 you don't print a newline. But in `amIOld` you print newlines before the text.

Comment: Note that you can omit the `age >= 13 &&` part in the `else if` test!

Comment: understood! got rid of the that age >= 13 condition, as it was of no use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the new line ending that you're putting at the beginning instead of at the end,

```
cout << "\nYou are old.";
```

Put them at the end should fix it.  These tests check for exact output, a lot of time the answer seem correct, but a slight output differences will fail the test case.

Explanation of why this fail: by putting end of line at the beginning you're assuming that there's an output/line already.  So in cases where initial age is not < 0, you don't have any output/line to start.  So you end up with outputting on the next line instead of where it should be.

Comment: thanks, substituting it with endl at the end fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

You need to put **this->age** as well on the second function

```
void Person::amIOld(){
    if(this->age < 13){ //you need to put this->age all age as well
        cout << "\nYou are young.";
    }
    else if (this->age >= 13 && this->age < 18) {//you need to put this->age all age as well
        cout << "\nYou are a teenager.";
    }
    else {
        cout << "\nYou are old.";
    }
}
```

Also you need to put **this->age** as well in the last function

```
void Person::yearPasses(){
    this->age++; //you need to put this->age all age as well
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#python 3

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self,initialAge):
        if initialAge < 3:
            print('Age is not valid, setting age to 0.')
            self.age = 0
        else:
            self.age = initialAge
        # Add some more code to run some checks on initialAge
    def amIOld(self):
        if self.age < 13:
            print("You are young.")
        elif self.age < 18:
            print("You are a teenager.")
        else:
            print("You are old. " , ) 
        # Do some computations in here and print out the correct statement to the console
    def yearPasses(self):
        self.age += 1
        # Increment the age of the person in here




t = int(input())
for i in range(0, t):
    age = int(input())         
    p = Person(age)  
    p.amIOld()
    for j in range(0, 3):
        p.yearPasses()       
    p.amIOld()
    print("")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).